# Osmdroid MylocationNewOverlay - setting the location update frequency

Tags: android, osmdroid

Is there a way to set the location update frequency? 
And also for the minimum distance?

Reason: I would like to set it in relation to battery savings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own instance of `GpsMyLocationProvider` and set those parameters.

```
GpsMyLocationProvider gpsLocationProvider = new GpsMyLocationProvider(context);
gpsLocationProvider.setLocationUpdateMinTime(...);
gpsLocationProvider.setLocationUpdateMinDistance(...);
mMyLocationNewOverlay.enableMyLocation(gpsLocationProvider);
```